# Why $\sin\left(\frac xy\right)$ is not equal to $\frac{\sin x}{\sin y}$ and why $\sin(x+y)$ is not equal to $\sin x+\sin y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Can someone explain to me why $\sin\left(\frac xy\right)$ is not equal to $\frac{\sin x}{\sin y}$, and as an extension, why this holds true for all trig functions? Also, why is $\sin(x+y)$ is not equal to $\sin x+\sin y$, and why does this holds true for all trig functions?

I get that this may be because they are functions, but what about the nature of trig functions causes the two to examples above to be not equal?

By the way, can you please keep the explanation very simple please? I am a high school student and may struggle to understand more complex explanations involving proof notation etc.

Comment: `why is sin(x+y) is not equal to sin(x)+sin(y)` See [Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation).

Comment: @dxiv I'm sorry, this is way too complex for me. It requires real analysis proofs, and stuff that I haven't learnt. Can you just explain the gist to me simply? I don't even understand what it means by a continuous function.

Comment: There is no reason why two expressions should give the same value just because they "kinda sorta look similar".  Do you have any reason to think that $\sin(x+y)$ should be the same as $\sin x+\sin y$?  Do you have any difficulty understanding that $(x+y)^2$ is not the same as $x^2+y^2$?

Comment: Do you know that $-1\leq \sin(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$? With this fact, it is really easy to see why your equalities cannot hold.

Comment: Why on earth **should** $\sin(x+y)$ be anything like $\sin x+\sin y$. I mean, the **graph** of $\sin$ is not a straight line is it?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: mh, can the OP make any connection between additivity of the function and straightness of the graph ?

Comment: it's best to try and understand them with geometry perhaps - https://www.math10.com/en/geometry/trigonometry-and-geometry-conversions/trigonometry.html

Comment: @Cato Thank you so much Cato, I think I finally get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assume $x=y\neq 0$ then

$$\sin(x/x)=\sin 1\neq \sin x/\sin x=1$$

and

$$\sin(x+x) =\sin (2x)=2\sin x\cos x\neq \sin x +\sin x=2\sin x$$

Comment: Does this tell "why" ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It depends how we consider the question "why?". To keep the explanation very simple, I've given some simple counterexamples to see "why it is not true" and we can find many others of them.

Comment: Why does it rain today ? Because the ground is wet.

Comment: @gimusi I largely get your answer, but how do we know that what you've written above is true even when y is not the same as x?

Comment: @EthanChan What we show by a counterexample is that the relations are not true in general and thus that they are false. Of course we can find some special cases for which they are true.

Comment: @EthanChan $1$ radians is $\approx 60°$ and $\sin x=1$ for $x=90°$

Comment: @gimusi Okay thanks. I think I get that now. But I'm still not sure how this shows that sin(x/y) is not equals to sin(x)/sin(y) outside of situations where y=x. How can we show that?

Comment: @EthanChan Let consider $x=\pi/2$ and $y=5\pi/2$.

Comment: @EthanChan: why did you accept the answer if you disagree with it ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't think that Ethan disagree at the moment, he is asking for some clarification. Anyway, I agree with you, it is not good accept an answer before one has understood that completely.

Answer (score 20):

A second of thinking tells you that no function achieves that !

$$\sqrt{x+y}\ne\sqrt x+\sqrt y,\frac1{x+y}\ne\frac1x+\frac1y,\log(x+y)\ne\log x+\log x,\cdots$$

$$\frac xy+1\ne\frac{x+1}{y+1},\tan\frac xy\ne\frac{\tan x}{\tan y}\cdots$$

---

There are just two exceptions:

$$a(x+y)=ax+ay$$

and

$$\left(\frac xy\right)^a=\frac{x^a}{y^a}.$$

So you'd better ask why the linear function is additive and why the power function is multiplicative.

---

If you want to find all additive functions, i.e. such that

$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y),$$ you immediately see that

$$f(2x)=2f(x)$$ and by induction

$$f(nx)=nf(x).$$

This generalizes to rationals,

$$qf\left(\frac pqx\right)=qpf\left(\frac xq\right)=pf(x)\implies f\left(\frac pqx\right)=\frac pqf(x),$$ and to reals

$$f(rx)=rf(x),$$ but the proof is more technical.

Now, setting $r\to x,x\to1$,

$$f(x)=f(1)\,x=ax.$$

---

For the multiplicative functions

$$g(xy)=g(x)g(y)$$

consider the function

$$f(x):=\log g(e^x)$$ and observe that it is additive, so that

$$f(x)=\log g(e^x)=ax,$$

$$g(e^x)=e^{ax},$$

$$g(x)=x^a.$$

Comment: Moreover, the only function satisfying both conditions at once is the identity.

Comment: The extension to reals only works if the function is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking at the universal statement:

> $\sin(x/y)$ is not equal to $\sin(x)/\sin(y)$, **for all $x$ and $y$**

This statement is false.

Let $x=\pi^2/(\pi + 2)$, $y=\pi/2$:
$$x/y=\pi-x$$
$$\sin(x/y)=\sin(x)$$
$$\sin(y)=1$$
$$\therefore \sin(x/y)=\sin(x)/\sin(y)$$

The universal statement:

> $\sin(x+y)$ is not equal to $\sin(x)+\sin(y)$, **for all $x$ and $y$**

is also false, since $\sin(2\pi)+\sin(4\pi)=\sin(2\pi+4\pi)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when $y=\pi$, $$\sin(x+y)=\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin x$$ but $$\sin x+\sin y=\sin x+\sin \pi=\sin x.$$

---

Also, when $x=2y$, $$\sin\left(\frac xy\right)=\sin2$$ whch is a constant for all $x,y\neq0$ but $$\frac{\sin x}{\sin y}=\frac{\sin 2y}{\sin y}=\frac{2\sin y\cos y}{\sin y}=2\cos y$$ which varies as $y$ varies.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$\sin(x+y)=2\sin\frac{x+y}2\cos\frac{x+y}2$$ and $$\sin(x)+\sin(y)=2\sin\frac{x+y}2\cos\frac{x-y}2.$$

The two expressions are equal when $$x+y=2k\pi$$ or when

$$\cos\frac{x+y}2=\cos\frac{x-y}2,$$

or

$$x+y=\pm(x-y)+4k\pi$$

which is true with

$$x=2k\pi\text{ or }y=2k\pi.$$

Hence $$\sin(x+y)=\sin x+\sin y$$ on a grid of step $2\pi$ plus all NW-SE diagonals.

---

The case of the division is much less tractable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers don't really address the heart of the question, and are too focused on proving why **@Ethan_Chan**'s equations are false *specifically* for trigonometric functions. Furthermore, I think **@Ethan_Chan**'s misunderstanding is on a more fundamental level.

$\sin(x)$ is a function, like any other. But why shouldn't every function satisfy $f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}$ or $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$? The reason is that a function can map different inputs ($x$ and $y$) to different outputs ($f(x)$ and $f(y)$). But the relationships between $x$ and $y$ aren't necessarily the same as the relationships between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$.

Let's think about what's happening to $x$ and $y$ in each of your examples. You're performing an operation on them: division ($\frac{x}{y}$) or addition ($x+y$). Let's denote an operation on $x$ and $y$ as $x*y$ (be it addition, subtraction, etc.). This brings us to a general rule for why your examples don't work:

$$\text{in general, }f(x*y)\neq f(x)*f(y)$$

**@Yves_Daoust**'s answer shows us the exceptions to this rule. But in general, it is true.